# How to overload spaceship operator (<=>) with reversed order?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, c++20, spaceship-operator

I'd like to implement `operator<=>` to a custom type `Bar` with a *reversed* ordering.

```cpp
struct Bar
{
    auto operator<=>(const Bar& rhs) const
    {
        // How to implement <=> on `int i`
        // But with reversed order
        // i.e., Bar{1} > Bar{2}
        
        // This definitely does not work
        return !(a <=> rhs.a);
    }
    int i;
};
```

Is there simpler way than using a `switch-case` to enumerate all the cases?

Comment: `return rhs.a <=> a;`?

Comment: It's not a boolean, it's an integer.  `-` would work better than `!`.

Comment: @TimRoberts it's not an integer either. It's a comparison category.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answers already point out that if you want to reverse `x <=> y` than the answer is simply `y <=> x`. We can just make a table and verify this:

|  | `x <=> y` | `y <=> x` |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `x == y` | `equal` | `equal` |
| `x < y` | `less` | `greater` |
| `x > y` | `greater` | `less` |

That's the easiest approach, just reverse the operands - since that's what you want to do, reverse the operation, by reversing the operands.

Another approach, which is useful in the case where you don't have the operands but do have the result (which is less likely but does come up) is `0 <=> (x <=> y)`:

| `x <=> y` | `0 <=> (x <=> y)` |
| --- | --- |
| `equal` | `equal` |
| `less` | `greater` |
| `greater` | `less` |

Conceptually, you can think of `<=>` as returning `-1`, `0`, or `1` (it doesn't, it returns a class type, but sometimes a small fiction helps us understand), so for instance you can think of `0 <=> less` as basically doing `0 <=> -1` which is `greater`, and likewise `0 <=> greater` as basically doing `0 <=> 1` which is `less`. You get the right answer, so as long as you don't fall into the trap of really thinking that these are `int`s and wanting to do more `int` math on them, you'll be fine.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is important to note the order doesn’t need the be “reversed” as much as the operator needs an implementation that matches the semantics you want or need in the class. I do note that the example is likely a minimised version of the situation you face and the “reverse” is that you want the ordering to be opposite of what the natural ordering is for integers.

The order of the comparison you are asking for can be done by reversing the order of the comparison of the `a` member;

```
// ...
auto operator<=>(const Bar& rhs) const
{
    return rhs.a <=> a;
}
// ...
```

Other changes can be made, but outside the scope of the immediate question.

Answer (score 0):

The `<=>` operator isn't commutative. Reversing the order of operands would also flip greater/less.

```cpp
struct Bar
{
    // note: overloading as a hidden friend is better than as a member
    //       function because it makes the function symmetrical regarding
    //       implicit conversions of arguments, and <=> is expected to be symmetrical
    friend auto operator<=>(const Bar& lhs, const Bar& rhs) noexcept
    {
        return rhs.i <=> lhs.i;
    }
    int i;
};
```

That being said, the behavior would be counter-intuitive because `<` is delegated to `<=>` automatically, and it would mean that `Bar{3} < Bar{1}`.

If you want to reverse a comparison case-by-case, do it by using `std::ranges::greater` instead of `std::ranges::less` when using an algorithm.
The `<=>` overload should still follow intuition, and a reversed one wouldn't.

---

See also [What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4421706/5740428).